# Finding footprints and symbols for common components

Tags: symbol, footprint

I am wanting to use a 5x2 IDC connector in my project which are quite common. Most IDC connectors such as [this one](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/cnc-tech/3020-10-0100-00/3441723) don't have a footprint or symbol. Which one do I use? Can I use any 5x2 connector provided it has the correct pitch i.e 2.54 mm in this case?

Comment: This isn't an IDC connector, it's just a shrouded pin header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts instead of having a single datasheet have an additional sheet with a drawing. If you scroll down the page you'll see it. It has the information you need to create a footprint.

[image: digikey screenshot]

Your PCB editing software should have a function to create custom footprints. If you're just starting out you may be surprised how often this is required.

Comment: I see, thank you. Man seems like a lot of effort for something that universal

Comment: Yeah it's annoying but you get used to it. You should be able to bang out a footprint for something like this in a couple of minutes once you get the hang of it.